# formatting hour and date data

Tags: r, datetime, format

I have some data in this format

```
 07.07.2016;22:00;3.00
 07.07.2016;23:00;3.00
 08.07.2016;00:00;3.00
 08.07.2016;01:00;3.00
 08.07.2016;02:00;3.00
 ...
```

and I want to format the hour and date data in an standart form that R can read.

EDIT:
how can I "find and replace" the "." in the date data, and how to add "00:" to the hour data ? I have no idea how to do it

Comment: Hi. We're not a free code writing service. Please explain what you've tried, what you had problems with and **ask a precise question**. Without a question, no chance for an answer.

Comment: I know is not a free code writing service. I have no idea how to "find and replace" the "." in the date data, and how to add "00:" to the hor data

Comment: You still haven't asked a question. And you need to show an attempt. A question is a sentence ending in "?"; and it needs to be a precise question, too.

Comment: how can I "find and replace" the "." in the date data, and how to add "00:" to the hour data ?

Comment: So a) **edit** your question to actually ask that question and b) **what have you tried?** *You need to show an attempt at solving your problem.*

Comment: Read about `lubridate` package, and `?gsub` function.

Comment: thanks ! the ?gsub function gave me a lot of ideas to solve this! i didnt knew it

Comment: Look at `?as.POSIXct` and `?strptime` for an answer in base R. This input can be read as is without reformatting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I would create just one datetime column:

```
mydf$datetimes <- strptime(paste(mydf$dates, mydf$times), format = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M')
```

now `mydf` looks like:

```
> mydf
       dates times value           datetimes
1 07.07.2016 22:00  3.00 2016-07-07 22:00:00
2 07.07.2016 23:00  3.00 2016-07-07 23:00:00
3 08.07.2016 00:00  3.00 2016-07-08 00:00:00
4 08.07.2016 01:00  3.00 2016-07-08 01:00:00
5 08.07.2016 02:00  3.00 2016-07-08 02:00:00
```

The data I used as input:

```
mydf <- structure(list(dates = c("07.07.2016", "07.07.2016", "08.07.2016", "08.07.2016", "08.07.2016"), 
                       times = c("22:00", "23:00", "00:00", "01:00", "02:00"), 
                       value = c("3.00", "3.00", "3.00", "3.00", "3.00")), 
                  .Names = c("dates", "times", "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```